# Cucumber Integration Test not seen by Maven Failsafe

Tags: junit5, micronaut, cucumber-java, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've created a Micronaut/Cucumber/JUnit5 test and am trying to run it as an integration test with Maven's Failsafe plugin.

When I run it as a normal test, Cucumber works properly. When I change the name of the test to `FooIT` and run `mvn verify`, Failsafe finds it but, claims there are no tests found.

`FooIT » NoTestsDiscovered Suite [foo.FooIT] did not discover any tests`

The test itself:

```
@MicronautCucumber
public class FooIT {
}
```

Definition of the `@MicronautCucumber` annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
@Documented
@Testable
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "long")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true")
// Add some tests to class
@SuppressWarnings("java:S2187")
public @interface MicronautCucumber {
}
```

Failsafe plugin entry in `pom.xml`

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Example project can be found at [this github repo](https://github.com/mlresnick/micronaut-cucumber-integration-failure)

Comment: If I run your project `foo.FooIT` and the `foo.feature` it selects are executed as expected.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje, thanks for confirming that the sample works. It got me to investigate and find the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is fine. I was using an alias for `mvn verify` that included a `-Dgroups=...` argument, so Maven was filtering out my intended test.